# React input handleInputChange() not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here is a small extract from a contact form I am making in a personal project.
In this condition the `handleInputChange()` on the email input works as expected (I can free-type in the field and the field updates dynamically).

```
const FeedbackForm = () => {
  let [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({ email: "" });

  const handleInputChange = (target) => {
    const updatedFormValues = {
      ...formValues,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    };
    setFormValues(updatedFormValues);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <input
            name="email"
            value={formValues.email}
            onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e.target)}
          />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
  );
};
```

Later in the development I decided I wanted to conditionally show/hide the email field so I abstracted it out to a separate component with a boolean prop to toggle the visibility of the element.

```
const FeedbackForm = ({
  emailFormFieldEnabled,
}) => {
  let [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({ email: "" });

  const handleInputChange = (target) => {
    const updatedFormValues = {
      ...formValues,
      [target.name]: target.value,
    };
    setFormValues(updatedFormValues);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  const EmailFormField = ({ visible }) => {
    if (!visible) {
      return null;
    }
    return (
        <input
          name="email"
          value={formValues.email}
          onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e.target)}
        />
    );
  };

  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <EmailFormField visible={emailFormFieldEnabled} />
        <button type="submit">
            Submit
        </button>
      </form>
  );
};
```

The toggling visibility works but this appears to have broken the `handleInputChange()` function. I can no longer free type in the input. I can select the input and type a single character but no more. If I want to type multiple characters in the field (like an email address, for example) I have to re-select the field to enter each character.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You have declared the `EmailFormField` component inside another component, so it's redeclared each render cycle. In other words, you are mounting a new instance each render cycle. Remounting the `EmailFormField` loses any focus the previous "instance" had.

## Solution

Declare `EmailFormField` *outside* the component and pass all the `value` and `onChange` props in.

Example:

```
const EmailFormField = ({ visible, value, onChange }) => {
  if (!visible) {
    return null;
  }
  return <input name="email" value={value} onChange={onChange} />;
};

const FeedbackForm = ({ emailFormFieldEnabled }) => {
  let [formValues, setFormValues] = useState({ email: "" });

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const updatedFormValues = {
      ...formValues,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    };
    setFormValues(updatedFormValues);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <EmailFormField
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        visible={emailFormFieldEnabled}
        value={formValues.email}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit react-input-handleinputchange-not-working]